# Get number of channels using SuperpoweredDecoder

Tags: c++, android-ndk, audio-processing, superpowered

Is it possible to get the number of channels of a .wav file using the SuperpoweredDecoder? I need this information for doing offline processing of .wav files with the superpowered sdk on android.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine/issues/141 the SuperpoweredDecoder always emits stereo audio.